# Ubuntu 18.04.1 does not boot without ethernet cable

Tags: boot, networking, ethernet, systemd

This is my **`/etc/network/interfaces`**:

```
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
```

This is my **`/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`**:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      addresses: [ 192.168.1.100/24 ]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
          addresses:
              - "8.8.8.8"
              - "8.8.4.4"
```

When the machine is connected to the network, it boots up fine. But whenever I take it over to my desk for maintenance, where there is no network cable, I am greeted with this:

[image: Error]

> A start job is running for Wait for Network to be Configured

How can I fix this, so I can boot the machine without an ethernet cable attached?

Comment: Wondering why your Ubuntu needs network to boot!

Comment: That is my question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually see this when I use static ip addresses on my virtual machines. As the `networkd` needs to setup your network or add your system to the network using this values so if the network isn't available it won't boot.

Modify your configurations and add the `optional: true` to prevent the system from wating during boot.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  enp0s25:
    addresses: [ 192.168.1.100/24 ]
    gateway4: 192.168.1.1
    nameservers:
       addresses:
         - "8.8.8.8"
         - "8.8.4.4"
    optional: true
```

Then try `sudo netplan try` and if all goes well apply `sudo netplan apply`.

Excerpt:

> Prevent waiting for interface
>   Interfaces that are not required for booting or should not be waited on during boot should have the optional: true key added to them. This will prevent long delays in booting for interfaces that may not come up.

See: https://netplan.io/faq